# Cannot load animation in ARKit from an .scn file

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit, arkit, caanimation

I'm loading a model (including one animation) contained in an .scn file using the following code:

```
// Recursively load all scene's nodes
let scene =  try! SCNScene(url: sceneFileURL, options: nil)
self.modelNode = SCNNode()
let nodeArray = scene.rootNode.childNodes
for childNode in nodeArray {
    self.modelNode?.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
}
```

I'm trying to load the animation in other part of the app. I first create the sceneSource object

```
self.sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: sceneFileURL, options: [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.animationImportPolicy : SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy.playRepeatedly])
```

then I look for the animation

```
for child in modelNode.childNodes {
   for key in child.animationKeys {
       print("add animation:\(key)")
       let animation = self.sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier(key, withClass: CAAnimation.self)
       //child.addAnimation(animation!, forKey: key)
       animation?.repeatCount = 10
       sceneView.scene.rootNode.addAnimation(animation!, forKey: key)
                }
}
```

Some debug information:

1) The loop can correctly find the animation key (it gets printed)

2) `SceneSource` is correctly initialised

**Problem**: `entryWithIdentifier` returns nil so I cannot load the animation

*Note*: If I use `addAnimation:ForKey` (currently deprecated so I would avoid it) I get an animation object but once added to the child note it has no effect on the model rendered in ARKit.

**Model available here**: https://files.fm/u/n7khpy58

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution?